# Is react only possible with node?

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

I was learning react from facebook https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html and I only find examples with node, once I saw one example using PHP but only for handling data, at the end a node server rendered the react.

Comment: It's purely a JS framework and doesn't care what backend you use. Node is used for isomorphic/universal apps (the server renders the first route's content) because it works well for that, but it's not essential to use React with.

Comment: As @DominicTobias said React doesn't care but node would be good to have for having Modular, Task Runner, Beautifying for the project since these modules are available in node (gulp, grunt, browserify, grunt-uglify etc)

Comment: No. Feel free to use whatever backend language you are comfortable with.
Advantage of node is it can serve rendered page on initial load (isomorphic/universal apps) I use React as client to PHP backend with no problems at all.

Comment: Node is used only in compile time, when you need to run babel/webpack. For your application, in a development or production environment you can use any language in your backend.